# Does MySQL contain some sort of contain function?

Tags: mysql

I would like to do some sort of search engine thing using MySQL such as when you have an input of like 'pple Inc.', you can search your table and return the row with the name 'Apple Inc.'. Is this something that is possible to do?

Comment: I think you're looking for `like`...

Comment: @sgeddes Ive tried like and it never seems to return anything unless its the exact string...

Comment: Are you using `%` with it?  `where col like '%val%'`

Comment: @sgeddes oops I forgot those... Thanks! While I'm at it, to check if it begins with val, would I just put the percent sign at the end?